# Как сменить цвет роли имея id роли и hex цвет discord.py?

Tags: python-3.x, бот, discord.py, discord-api

Я посмотрел документацию, понял только как использовать `ID`:

```
role = member.guild.get_role(767446695294140426)
```

Больше ничего не понял + цвет должен быть в каком-то типе `Union`.

Мне надо чтобы при прописывании команды роль меняла свой цвет.

*Документация: https://waa.ai/tzMr (сокращённая ссылка)*

`Fixator10`, надеюсь ты мне снова поможешь)

(Я новичок)
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[typing.Union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union)

[discord.Role.edit](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Role.edit)

```py
await role.edit(color=0x378cdc)
# или
await role.edit(color=discord.Color(0x378cdc))
```